# Most up-to-date authentication in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I see posts from all sorts of time period talking about pre-built authentication plugins such as restful authentication - but looking at it, it seems that it wasn't updated since April 2008.

So I ask, what is the most current pre-built authentication plugin for rails 2.3.5?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/) allows you to review the popularity and last updates of different libraries or Rails plugins.

Check the current status of [authentication plugins](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication.html) and you'll find [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) is both recently updated and the most popular.

Answer (score 5):

[clearance](http://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance) - last update January 20, 2010

or

[authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) - last update January 19, 2010

Cheers

Comment: thank you. what is the most widely use authentication system in rails?

Answer (score 1):

I think authlogic is mostly used.

Answer (score 1):

Also [Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is still updated (some changes were commited yesterday) - it works well, but I agree with nanda, that Authlogic is the most popular plugin.